# ¿Como despierto a un proceso especifico de entre muchos que esperan en un semáforo en C?

Tags: c

Se me ha planteado un ejercicio en el que necesito realizar la implementación de un semáforo para varios procesos, el problema es que esos procesos tienen un orden de ejecución y si simplemente hago un "sem_post" se despiertan todos y uno al azar entra, para luego volver a dormirse el resto.

Necesito una manera de que entre solo el que yo quiero a ejecutarse. ¿Alguien sería capaz de decirme como se hace esto?

PD: No puedo usar Mutex como tal, aunque el semáforo puede ser inicializado con el valor que sea.

Debo hacer un programa teórico en el que desde un programa padre mediante fork y exec tengo que llamar a otros, estos procesos tienen un orden especifico de ejecución, el orden en el que están escritos en un fichero, y debo controlar este orden en todo momento. En su inicio todos deben estar bloqueados y yo debo ir desbloqueándolos uno a uno según su orden. Un posible esquema sería el siguiente:

```
Leo el fichero
Meto en un array de struct con los datos de los procesos
Creo un semáforo y lo abro
pid=fork

    if(pid == 0){ execvp("nom_program",var1,var2,var3,null)
    /Las variables sacadas del struct/

-----DENTRO DEL EXEC------
abro el semáforo hago un wait() y espero a que el padre me diga que puedo continuar
----------FIN EXEC----------------
}

else(o sea el padre){
Aqui es donde me atasco, no se como usar ese único semáforo para despertar a un único hijo,
el hijo que, por orden, debe ejecutarse.}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar una variable para indicar el hilo que debe despertarse. Si sabes el ID del hilo puedes almacenar en dicha variable es ID... si no lo sabes tendrás que pensar otra forma de identificarlos (como no das más detalles esta parte corre de tu cuenta).

```
sem_t mutex; // Asumo esta variable para el semaforo
int hiloADespertar;

if( /* para cada hilo */ )
{
  while(1)
  {
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    if( hiloADespertar == /* miHilo */ )
      break;
    sem_post(&mutex); // Se libera el semaforo para que otro hilo pruebe suerte
  }
}
else /* para el hilo padre */
{
  hiloADespertar =  /* ... */;
  sem_post(&mutex); // se libera el semaforo
}
```

Otra posibilidad es tener varios semáforos, uno por cada hilo, y liberar el semáforo que te interese en cada ocasión.

Comment: Es perfecto. ¡Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @AlfonsoRodríguez si la respuesta soluciona tu problema no olvides marcarla como "_solución_"

Comment: Disculpa soy nuevo en esto, y aun estoy aprendiendo. Me ha servido mucho, ¡Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: @AlfonsoRodríguez no pasa nada. Todos hemos pasado por eso.